# DebuggerVisualizer not showing up when debugging but works on test application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debuggervisualizer

I have made a DebuggerVisualizer to show a simple Image of an abstract Puzzle class - the issue I'm having is that in my test application that simply creates a puzzle and calls TestShowVisualizer() the image is displayed correctly on screen. However when debugging the project and hovering over the variable there is no visualizer (or magnifying glass icon)

```
    public abstract class Puzzle
    {
         // Lots of properties and methods here //

         public static Puzzle Load(StreamReader sr)
         {
           // Reads the stream reader and creates the correct derived class
         }

         public abstract Image GenerateNet();
    }


        [DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(PuzzleVisualizer), typeof(PuzzleVisualizerObjectSource), Description = "Image Visualizer", Target = typeof(Puzzle))]
public class PuzzleVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
{
    protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
    {
        var puz = Puzzle.Load(new StreamReader(objectProvider.GetData()));
        var image = puz.GenerateNet();

        var form = new Form
        {
            Text = $"Width: {image.Width}, Height: {image.Height}",
            ClientSize = new Size(image.Width, image.Height),
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
        };

        var pictureBox = new PictureBox
        {
            Image = image,
            Parent = form,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };

        windowService.ShowDialog(form);
    }

    public static void TestShowVisualizer(object objectToVisualize)
    {
        var visualizerHost = new VisualizerDevelopmentHost(objectToVisualize, typeof(PuzzleVisualizer), typeof(PuzzleVisualizerObjectSource));
        visualizerHost.ShowVisualizer();
    }
}
```

I made a test application which all the examples for making visualizers use too:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Cube222();
        p.Setup();
        PuzzleVisualizer.TestShowVisualizer(p);
        return;
    }
}
```

The visualizer works when TestShowVisualizer() is called but not for just general debugging.

I've made sure that the visualizer class is in its own DLL and that this gets copied to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You put the [attribute] on the wrong class.   The Puzzle class need it, not the visualizer class.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason for this, it was because the `DebuggerVisualizer` attribute needs to be applied to the namespace not the class.

So

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;
using PuzzleExplorer.Visualizers;

[assembly:DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(PuzzleVisualizer), typeof(PuzzleVisualizerObjectSource), Description = "Puzzle Visualizer", Target = typeof(Puzzle))]
namespace PuzzleExplorer.Visualizers
{
    public class PuzzleVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
        // code
        }
    }
 }
```

I read the tutorial and it does make it clear but I somehow missed it.

> Add the following attribute code to DebuggerSide.cs, after the using statements but before namespace MyFirstVisualizer: